# call a function using window[variablename](); in document.ready

Tags: javascript

I have functions in side a **document.ready** and I want to call them using value inside a variable.. I tried to use `window[variablename]();` but it is not working inside **document.ready** but when called it directly it works..

think this is the function inside the document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function jhon(){
         alert('works');
    };
});
```

I'm getting function name from a variable,value of that variable is the name of the function..

below code will get the URL's hashed part example: #JHON and remove # and store it inside URLHASH variable..example: JHON

```
  var urlhash = document.location.hash;
  urlhash = urlhash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
```

when I called like this it is not working..

```
  window.onload=function() {
      window[urlhash]();
  };
```

but when I call the function like this it is working fine..

```
  window.onload=function() {
      jhon();
  };
```

Is it possible to call a function using variable value?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/wzpcx/. It works for me.

Comment: nut when i placed alert(urlhash); before window[urlhash](); it alerts with correct value but window[urlhash](); doesnt call the function

Comment: You could use `var urlhash=document.location.hash.substring(1)` instead of replacing regular expressions.

Comment: You have coded wrong both codes should be inside the doument.ready because you cannot call document,ready function from outside.. http://jsfiddle.net/wzpcx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function `jhon` *outside* of `$(document).ready`. Otherwise, it'll be hidden, and thus inaccessible via `window[function_name]`:

```
function jhon(){
     alert('works');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var urlhash = document.location.hash;
  urlhash = urlhash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
  window[urlhash]();
});
```

Comment: I added here a example not the real code..what real code do is sliding one div to another..it is impossible to define it out side.. thing is it works when it called jhon(); inside document.ready but when it called window[urlhash](); inside document.ready it is not working..

Comment: Yes, because the function is not defined in `window`. Try to do `window.jhon = function () { alert('works') }` instead.

Comment: okay if i do so will it also work when i called like jhone(); ?

Comment: okay if i do so will it also work when i called like jhone(); ?

Comment: If you define `window.jhone` yes.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
window.onload=function() {
    window[urlhashed]();
};
```

Contains a typo: `urlhashed` ought to be `urlhash`

```
window.onload=function() {
    window[urlhash]();
};
```

In addition to that you have defined `jhon()` inside of another function, which capture's it in that enclosing functions scope.

if you want to have this work as intended you ought to change this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function jhon(){
         alert('works');
    };
});
```

to be more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.jhon = function(){
         alert('works');
    };
});
```

Comment: Depending on your runtime scenario @Joao's answer might suit you better.